# Error when trying to add permissions to a group in django admin panel

Tags: django, python-3.x, postgresql

I am trying to add a few existing permissions to the group inside the django admin panel. But its showing the below error and I haven't got a clue why its happening.

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/auth/group/4/change/

Django Version: 3.0.6
Python Version: 3.8.2
Installed Applications:
['exams.apps.ExamsConfig',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'bootstrap4']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/defiant/Projects/Python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 86, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

The above exception (syntax error at or near "ON"
LINE 1: ...ons" ("group_id", "permission_id") VALUES (4, 20) ON CONFLIC...
                                                             ^
) was the direct cause of the following exception:
  File "/Users/defiant/Projects/Python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/Users/defiant/Projects/Python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/Users/defiant/Projects/Python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/Users/defiant/Projects/Python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 607, in wrapper
    return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/defiant/Projects/Python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 130, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/defiant/Projects/Python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py", line 44, in _wrapped_view_func
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/defiant/Projects/Python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py", line 231, in inner
    return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/defiant/Projects/Python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 1641, in change_view
    return self.changeform_view(request, object_id, form_url, extra_context)
  File "/Users/defiant/Projects/Python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 43, in _wrapper
    return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/defiant/Projects/Python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 130, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/defiant/Projects/Python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 1522, in changeform_view
    return self._changeform_view(request, object_id, form_url, extra_context)
  File "/Users/defiant/Projects/Python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 1566, in _changeform_view
    self.save_related(request, form, formsets, not add)
  File "/Users/defiant/Projects/Python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 1107, in save_related
    form.save_m2m()
  File "/Users/defiant/Projects/Python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/forms/models.py", line 442, in _save_m2m
    f.save_form_data(self.instance, cleaned_data[f.name])
  File "/Users/defiant/Projects/Python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py", line 1618, in save_form_data
    getattr(instance, self.attname).set(data)
  File "/Users/defiant/Projects/Python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related_descriptors.py", line 1008, in set
    self.add(*new_objs, through_defaults=through_defaults)
  File "/Users/defiant/Projects/Python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related_descriptors.py", line 944, in add
    self._add_items(
  File "/Users/defiant/Projects/Python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related_descriptors.py", line 1123, in _add_items
    self.through._default_manager.using(db).bulk_create([
  File "/Users/defiant/Projects/Python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 492, in bulk_create
    returned_columns = self._batched_insert(
  File "/Users/defiant/Projects/Python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1230, in _batched_insert
    self._insert(item, fields=fields, using=self.db, ignore_conflicts=ignore_conflicts)
  File "/Users/defiant/Projects/Python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1204, in _insert
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(returning_fields)
  File "/Users/defiant/Projects/Python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1391, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/defiant/Projects/Python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 100, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/defiant/Projects/Python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 68, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "/Users/defiant/Projects/Python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 77, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "/Users/defiant/Projects/Python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 86, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/defiant/Projects/Python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/Users/defiant/Projects/Python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 86, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

Exception Type: ProgrammingError at /admin/auth/group/4/change/
Exception Value: syntax error at or near "ON"
LINE 1: ...ons" ("group_id", "permission_id") VALUES (4, 20) ON CONFLIC...
                                                         ^
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It had something to do with the postgres version I was using. Used the latest docker image for hosting the db and the error was gone.